# NSRange returning nil in simulator

Tags: nsstring, nsmutablearray, null, nsrange

I am making a search function and it works fine on an iphone and the iphone simulator but not the ipad simulator. When I enter my value to search it gives the error basically saying the NSRange is nil:

'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSCFString rangeOfString:options:range:locale:]: nil argument'

Heres what I have.

```
for (int i = 0, c = names.count; i < c; ++i) {
   sFirst = [firstArray objectAtIndex:i];
   sSecond = [secondArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSRange result = [sFirst rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    NSRange r = [sSecond rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    if (result.location != NSNotFound) {
        [searchedFirst addObject:sFirst];
        [searchedSecond addObject:sSecond];
    }    
    if (r.location != NSNotFound) {
        [searchedFirst addObject:sFirst];
        [searchedSecond addObject:sSecond];
    }    

}
```

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening, or is there anything I can do about this problem? Should I not worry about it since its working fine on an actual device?

**SOLVED**
I guess since i was calling the searchText (or searchBar.text) without changing the value into a string first it returned nil. So I just declared a string in the header file.

```
stringValue = searchBar.text;
```

Answer (score 2):

An NSRange cannot be nil - it's not an object, not even a pointer.

It's most probably `searchText` that is nil.

And if it's buggy either on the simulator or on the device, you must fix it because it **will** fail some day.

Comment: I thought that at first too. i checked out the searchText, which i actually changed to searchBar.text, has a value.